# Get youku video thumbnail in PHP

Tags: php, video, video-thumbnails, youku

I've been trying to find information for obtaining a video thumbnail from a youku video. Most search results are unsurprisingly in Chinese. The best solution I've found so far basically scrapes the entire page:

```
preg_match_all( '~youku.com/embed/(.*?)\"~si',$embed_string,$M);
if (!empty($M[1]))  $video_id = ($M[1][0]);
$request = "http://v.youku.com/player/getPlayList/VideoIDS/$video_id/";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$result = json_decode($response);
$youku_img_path = $result->data[0]->logo;
```

The problem is that if I want to include more than one thumbnail on the page, it very quickly starts to slow down performance. Also, Youku sometimes seems to not allow the request, making this solution unreliable at best. Does anyone know any better solutions?

Comment: I’d try using their API instead – http://open.youku.com/docs/api/videos/show_basic the result of that includes a `thumbnail`, I think that should be a URL. Now all you have to do is sign up on that site for an API key somehow ;-)

Comment: Thanks, it's something to go on, though if anyone has had experience of this I'd prefer not to rely on Google translate.

Comment: @CBroe: I can't sign up to OPEN API from India, captcha os the problem for me. I guess Google Translates it in English but they are matching it against Chinese characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know chinese, but they've an open API to get video info: http://open.youku.com/docs/api/videos/show for a single video and http://open.youku.com/docs/api/videos/show_batch for more than one video.

You'll have to register with them [here](http://open.youku.com/) to get an API key to use in each request.

Comment: Ok thanks Paulo and CBroe, looks like it's time to get out the Chinese dictionary...

Comment: @GluePear You're welcome! I think it'll be boring only to get an API key, API docs are easy to grasp. :)

Answer (score 0):

Now youku has english version website, you can easily apply an api key through:http://open.youku.com/app

```
function youkuapi($vid){
$url="https://openapi.youku.com/v2/videos/show_basic.json?video_id=".$vid."&client_id=your_api_key";
$data=file_get_contents($url);
$json=json_decode($data,true);
return $json;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "How to get a thumbnail"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
http://events.youku.com/global/api/video-thumb.php?vid=YOUKU_VIDEO_ID
```

Swap out YOUKU_VIDEO_ID with your video ID.

Comment: Works, but thumbnail is small